# Python variable scope for exec?

Tags: python, dynamic, exec

Below are 2 code snippets.

I would like to duplicate the effect of `f1`, where an outer variable `x` is modified by an inner function `g`.

However, instead of defining an inner function `g`, `g` is obtained by executing/interpreting a string.

code:

```
def f1():
  x = []
  def g():
    x.append(1)
  g() 
  print x


def f2():
  x = []
  strr = "def g():\n  x.append(1)\n"
  exec(strr)
  locals()["g"]()
  print x
```

In `f1` I get [1] as the print out, but in `f2` I get `x undefined` error. I would like to know how I can make the variable `x` accessible in the string-defined function `g`.

follow up:

What would happen if I want to apply a decorator to g? say I have a "timeout" decorator that fails a function if it takes too long to run:

```
def f1():
  x = []
  @timeout(1)
  def g():
    x.append(1)
  g() 
  print x
```

edit: I managed to solve it as follows, since timeout is not defined locally, I have to move the definition of timeout from global to local, the proceed as usual.

```
def f2():
  x = []
  strr = "@timeout(1)\ndef g():\n  x.append(1)\n"
  locals()['timeout'] = globals()['timeout']
  exec strr in locals()
  locals()["g"]()
  print x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the name space for `exec`. Use the local name space (`exec strr in locals()`) and it works:

```
def f2():
    x = []
    strr = "def g():\n  x.append(1)\n"
    exec strr in locals()
    locals()["g"]()
    print x

>>> f2()
[1]
```

Comment: Anyone able to reproduce this in python 3?

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3, use this.

```py
def f2():
    x = []
    strr = "def g():\n  x.append(1)\n"
    exec(strr, locals())
    locals()["g"]()
    print(x)
f2()
```